# How can I turn an OneSignal subscription link (javascript) into a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onesignal

I have the code for the CSS of the button and the subscription javascript of OneSignal. The plain javascript just shows the text as a link, and I want to create a button instead, but when I try to put the CSS on the code it just seems like a highlight in the text and becomes so hard to click on it (it's clickable only on the top of the text).

The OneSignal code is

```html
<body>
<a href="#" id="subscribe-link" style="display: none;">Click here to subscribe</a>
    <script>
        function subscribe() {
            OneSignal.push(["registerForPushNotifications"]);
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        var OneSignal = OneSignal || [];
        /* This example assumes you've already initialized OneSignal */
        OneSignal.push(function() {
            // If we're on an unsupported browser, do nothing
            if (!OneSignal.isPushNotificationsSupported()) {
                return;
            }
            OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled(function(isEnabled) {
                if (isEnabled) {
                    // The user is subscribed to notifications
                    // Don't show anything
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("subscribe-link").addEventListener('click', subscribe);
                    document.getElementById("subscribe-link").style.display = '';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

And my CSS code is

```html
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
.subscribe-link {
    background: #F76A0C; 
    width: 200px; 
    text-align: center; 
 float:right
}

.subscribe-link a {
    color: #fff; 
    display:block;
    padding: 13px 0px;
 
}

.subscribe-link a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #FA9450; 

}
</style>
</head>
```

Is there other way to put the CSS on the code? I really need to show a button instead of pure text. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can define the html button with the id = 'subscribe-link' and remove the  tag.

```
<button id="subscribe-link" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

EDIT (add the screen-shot):

[image]

Comment: it turned into a white rectangle with no text on it and it does nothing when clicked... Am I doing something wrong? I just replaced the href part.

Comment: I have a typo. On the other hand, have you initialised OneSignal already?

Comment: yes, I have the code that create the bell icon in the page, the code I want to put in the button is an extra option to subscribe, I will set it as blog post footer.  It works fine without the CSS

Comment: After you add  id="subscribe-link"  into your existing icon tag. It should added the event listener. When the button is click, it will call the subscribe() functions. Is it working fine?

Comment: Yes, the whole thing works at all, I'm just having problems to make it a button with CSS because it looks ugly like a highlighted text, and not a button as I want.